# What's the best way to mass email cases in Service Cloud?

Tags: servicecloud, email2case, mass-email, mass-action

Our customer services team has a requirement to bulk reply to cases using email templates, so they can respond to hundreds of cases at the same time. I saw that Mass Email Cases was an option in Salesforce Classic, but cases originating via email-to-case don't appear to be available using this feature.

Has anyone put a similar feature in place before? I assume it's possible with auto-replies for different queues etc but was hoping this might be something that's been achieved in a better way.

Comment: bulk macros can work against list view; macros can send emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One item to look at would be (which we use in our org)

Macros -- these are canned steps of actions to take based on either the current case or a selected set of cases from a listview

[Learn About Macros, Service Console, and Case Feed](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/service-cloud-essentials-features/learn-about-macros-service-console-and-case-feed)

- layout needs to be feed-based
- works in Service Console
- you can [configure some users to have bulk macro support](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/service-cloud-agent-productivity/set-up-the-productivity-tools) whereas others can only apply a macro to a single Case

So, if you can define a listview that locates all the cases that need a common reply; then define an email template, select the cases in the listview within Service Console, apply the macro and bingo, hundreds of emails go out in one click.